# D3 - responsively show/hide bars totals on top of bars

Tags: d3.js

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/basic-bar-mt-kucbu1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbar-chart.ts)

It's a responsive D3 chart in an Angular app, resizing the window will keep the height the same but reduce the width.

The bars have totals above them that can overlap when the chart is resized.

Is there a way to resoponsively hide and show the totals, for example if there isn't enough room only show the total on every other bar an then every thrid bar etc.

```
private drawTotal(data){

  const text = this.chart.selectAll(".text")
    .data(data)

    ///Enter
    text.enter()
      .append("text")
      .classed('text', true)
      .text( (d) => (d.value))
      .attr('x', (d) => this.x(d.date)+this.x.bandwidth()/2)
      .attr("y", this.height)
      .attr("y", (d) => this.y(d.value)-10)
      .attr("height", (d) => this.height - this.y(d.value))
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle");

    text
      .attr('x', (d) => this.x(d.date)+this.x.bandwidth()/2)
      .attr("y", this.height)
      .attr("y", (d) => this.y(d.value)-10)
      .attr("height", (d) => this.height - this.y(d.value))

    text.exit()
      .remove()    
    };
```